# TypeScript - accessing a property of an undefined object is not throwing any errors

Tags: typescript

```
const testResult = config.layers?.find((layer) => layer.id === 'blah')?.dataSource!;
console.log('testResult: ', testResult);
```

I have a object called Configuration (imported as "config"), and it consists of an array of Layers.

Each layer has an "id".

I do not have an id called "blah", so why does this print out **testResult: undefined**

I would have expected a runtime error.

To my understanding, "!" says that the variable cannot be undefined, but the .find() method would have returned an undefined object, for which ".dataSource" should not be accessible.

I'm confused!!

Do I potentially have some setting in place which causes this behaviour?

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "google",
        "react-app",
        "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:react/jsx-runtime",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "plugin:jest/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": "2018",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "project": ["tsconfig.test.json"]
    },
    "plugins": ["react", "jsx-a11y", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier", "jest"],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "off",
        "require-jsdoc": [
            "error",
            {
                "require": {
                    "FunctionDeclaration": false,
                    "MethodDefinition": false,
                    "ClassDeclaration": false,
                    "ArrowFunctionExpression": false,
                    "FunctionExpression": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "jest/no-disabled-tests": "warn",
        "jest/no-focused-tests": "error",
        "jest/no-identical-title": "error",
        "jest/prefer-to-have-length": "warn",
        "jest/valid-expect": "error"
    }
}
```

Comment: What runtime error would you expect?  You're not trying to dereference any properties of `testResult`.  You are using optional chaining so `?.dataSource` will not itself throw a runtime error.  If you could [edit] to provide a [mre] we can test ourselves in our own IDEs (not just a verbal description of your types and values, since my IDE doesn't understand such things), we can be more specific and write up a testable and confirmable answer.

Comment: Your tsconfig isn't terribly relevant here.  Instead we'd need a [mre], such as the one shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mxJ9bw).  Would you [edit] to use that code instead?  Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding what the `!` does. It just tells the TS language server to ignore any risk of `dataSource` being undefined.

In addition, you are misunderstanding TypeScript - it won't throw errors, because when code is executed it's vanilla javascript. Typescript helps you write better and safer code, but it doesn't change your runtime behaviour.

By using `!` you say: "I know for sure that dataSource exists", hence don't show me errors in the IDE. This operator essentially performs [**non null assertition**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html)

However, as it turns out it is undefined, either because `dataSource` is undefined, or because `find()` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is beacuase of the [Optional Chaining (`?`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) you've used.

`const testResult = config.layers?.find((layer) => layer.id === 'blah')?.dataSource!;`

If `config.layers` is `undefined`, the `find` method is never called on it and JavaScript just defaults to `testResult` resulting in `undefined`.

This happens all the way down too, so if `find` doesn't return anything, then the `dataSource` property is also not accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Your "error" has nothing to do with TypeScript typing and everything to do with regular JavaScript behavior.

If you use optional chaining, you are telling JavaScript to check the value to the left of the chain, and if it's nullish (`null` or `undefined`), short-circuit the operation to the right. Take the following, for example:

```js
const foo = {
  a: 'abc',
  b: null,
};

console.log(foo.b.length);
console.log(foo.b?.length);
```

The first log will throw an error because `foo.b` is null and trying to access `length` on a null reference isn't allowed. But the second log will print "null" because the `b?.length` is saying "Only access `length` if `b` isn't `null`, otherwise return `null`."

So when you do:

```js
config.layers?.find(...)?.dataSource!
```

You are asserting that `dataSource` is non-null here, but you also have optional chaining on `layers` and `find(...)`. If either of those expressions returns a nullish value, execution stops on that entire line of code, and the execution will never reach `dataSource!`.

If you want to apply the non-null assertion to the entire line, you will need to wrap the entire line in parentheses:

```js
(config.layers?.find(...)?.dataSource)!
```

Though at this point, you better be really sure about what you're doing, because you're effectively throwing TypeScript compile-time null-safety out the window.